# Unable to login after creating a user name and password in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to create a user and password for SQL Server authentication so I wrote the below code (Database = Master)

```
Create Login Khurram 
with password = 'mypassword';
go

Create user iamtheuser for login khurram;
go
```

and then changed the server security option to the Sql Server and Windows Authentication Mode but I get the below error when I try to login:

> Login failed for user khurram (Microsoft Sql Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: The SQL Server error log will contain more specifics about the reason for the login failure. Did you restart SQL Server after changing the authentication mode?

Comment: I disconnected and tried to connect with the login credentials but I could not. I can see the user name listed under the Logins folder and when I try to run the query again, it gives me the below error messages      Msg 15025, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The server principal 'Khurram' already exists.
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
User, group, or role 'iamtheuser' already exists in the current database.

Comment: Check the logs, like Dan said. What is the *actual* error for the connection? My guess, you're trying to connect to a database that the `LOGIN`doesn't have a mapped `USER` for.

Comment: Here is what the log says  "Server is connected for Integrated Authentication only" but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: See [Change server authentication mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15). You're trying to use a SQL Authenication Login on a server that does not allow those connections.

Comment: @khurramShahzad, again, did you restart SQL Server? A restart is required before the change is effective.

Comment: @ Dan, I have done it but I get the same error. I am using the SQL Server on my local machine so does this make any difference?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter where SQL Server is running as long as you changed the setting on the correct instance. The SQL Server error log will include a message indicating the configured authentication mode at startup. Make sure it says "Authentication mode is MIXED" and, if not, try changing it again.

Comment: @Larnu, you are spot on the issue was with the mapping so now it is fixed and now I am able to login.

Comment: @Larnu, how can I mark you answer correct, please let me know.